# Change certain blocks to other blocks?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

What command changes all emerald to white wool? I have tried the /fill command, but that changes all the blocks in the area.

Answer (score 1):

The link that MBraedley posted has your answer.

To change cobblestone to stone

`/fill <x1> <y1> <z1> <x2> <y2> <z2> stone 0 replace cobblestone`

Or to change emerald to white wool

`/fill <x1> <y1> <z1> <x2> <y2> <z2> wool 0 replace emerald_block`

Change `<x1> <y1> <z1>` to the coordinates of one corner of the rectangular area, and `<x2> <y2> <z2>` with the coordinates of the opposite corner.

Comment: What does the 0 after the new block specify?